# Find how high up the camera is looking with a rotation Matrix

Tags: frame-rate, rotational-matrices

I'm working on an FPS with the jPCT library.  One key thing that all FPS's need is to prevent the players from looking behind them by pulling the mouse too far up/down.  Currently, I'm using some example code found on the jPCT's website that keeps track of how many angles have been added to the camera, but I'm worried about rounding issues with all the angles in radians.  I can get a rotation Matrix from jPCT's camera, and I know that it contains the information to figure out how "high" up the player is looking, but I have no clue how to get it out of the matrix.

What would I look for in the rotation matrix that will tell me if the player is looking more "up" than strait up and more "down" than strait down?

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating your matrix each time the player moves you're going to run into trouble due to floating point errors and your rotation matrix will turn into a skew matrix. One solution is to orthonormalise the matrix every now and then but usually it's better to simply keep the player's pitch, yaw (and roll if you need it) as floats and build your matrix from those angles when the player changes orientation, looks up/down etc. If you use optimised code for each angle (or a single method for converting Euler angles to a matrix) it's not slower than what you seem to be doing right now. You won't run into Gimbal lock issues as the camera orientation will be restricted anyway.

As for your specific question I think you'd need to calculate the angle between matrix Z axis (the third row or column, depends how your matrices are oriented) and an unrotated vector pointing down your Z axis.

Comment: First of all, I can't just store the pitch, yaw, and roll because jPCT doesn't provide a way to just set the angles of rotation, only to rotate by it.  I want to avoid keeping track of the angles because there's no way to correct the camera.  Second, HOW would I calculate the angle between the Z axis?  Third, didn't you mean the Y axis, as it's the up and down for 3D modeling?

Comment: 1. I meant to calculate the rotation matrix yourself from the angles, then you can submit it to your renderer as before. 2. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=angle+between+vectors 3. Either would do, it's up to you which one you choose -- with Z (horizontal) angles will be +/- 80 degrees (or whatever limit you set), with Y (vertical) it'll be etc. 10-170. I personally prefer +/- but it's up to you.